# How to do SSR (server-side rendering) in Svelte/TypeScript?

Tags: server-side-rendering, svelte

Svelte’s JavaScript server-side rendering API is described here: https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-server-side-component-api

However, when I do this in TypeScript, there is no method `App.render()`.

- Do I need to change `rollup.config.js` (e.g. `compilerOptions.generate`)?
- Do I need two versions of this file – one for the server and one for the client?

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Svelte [Server-side component API](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-server-side-component-api) is not directly accessible via import. Instead, you need to build the production with vite options `--ssr`. Otherwise, you're importing the component class extended `SvelteComponent` and that class has no `render` function.

You can check out this guide for Production SSR build: [Vite Server-Side Rendering](https://vitejs.dev/guide/ssr.html).

You don't need to set up the SSR Dev server or inject `/@vite/client` because [svelte-hmr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-hmr) already does the magic under the hood.

The SSR Bundle options `ssr.noExternal` doesn't seem to work for me. So that I need to convert all Svelte components import into static `import` for a production build.

Answer (score 0):

The [official template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) relies on **rollup-plugin-svelte**, where [similar question](https://github.com/sveltejs/rollup-plugin-svelte/issues/64) was asked. Essentially compiling in SSR mode does not automatically generate any HTML, in fact some post processing is required. The  Svelte [Server-side component API](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-server-side-component-api) can be used for that.

There are several solutions out there for SSR:

- [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/)
- [Routify](https://www.routify.dev/)
- [ElderJS](https://elderguide.com/tech/elderjs/)

Comment: Thanks! The Server-side component API is all I need (see first line of my question). However, I can’t access this API when I’m using TypeScript.